# LARAVEL - Usar bcrypt en una columna con tinker

Tags: laravel

se perfectamente que usando tinker puedo crear nuevos registros en base a un modelo.

```
$user = new App\Datos;
>>> $user->name = 'jeff';
>>> $datos->email = 'jeffer.8a@gmail.com';
>>> $datos->password = bcrypt('12345');
```

*Pero!..* como lograria qué el `bcrypt` afecte a toda la columna password. Esto debido a que los datos que tengo de esa columna no están encriptados.

Comment: Ósea actualizar todos?

Answer (score 0):

Deberías hacerlo de este modo:

```
$data = \DB::table("datos")->update(array("password" => bcrypt("password")));
```

1. Es decir haciendo uso del facade `DB` accedemos al nombre de la tabla
2. posterior accedemos al método `update()` y le pasamos en forma de array asociativo la columna que queremos actualizar y posterior el valor que desamos generar, usando el método `bcrypt()` para cifrarla

**NOTA IMPORTANTE**

`bcrypt` va a generar un dato de tipo alfanumérico por lo cual es importante que la columna sobre la cual vas a ejecutar la actualización soporte esto, pudiendo ser un `VARCHAR` en caso contrario obtendrías un error

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si la actualización no es masiva y quieres aplicar un `where` para indicar que valores se deben actualizar; debes hacer lo siguiente

Aqui por ejemplo le indicamos que solo actualice si el id es igual a 2

```
$data = \DB::table("datos")->where('id', 2)->update(array("password" => bcrypt("password")));
```

Si por el contrario quieres ejecutar la actualización a un grupo de valores especificos pero no a todos; entonces has lo siguiente

```
$data = \DB::table("datos")
        ->whereIn('id', [1, 3])
        ->update(array("password" => bcrypt("password")));
```

Como notas usé el método `whereIn()` donde el primer argumento es el nombre de la columna y posterior en forma de arreglo separado por comas el rango de valores que serán modificados o actualizados